# Non-square n-dimensional input in tflearn / understanding shapes

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

i was wondering: what is the best way to deal with n-dimensional input data where each dimension has a different length? So lets say my input data looks like this:

```
input_data = n.array([
    [[0.4, -0.3, 0.43, 0.23], [5, 8]],
    [[0.3, -0.2, 0.34, 0.32], [4, 7]],
])
```

So i could imagine that it is simply not possible to feed this as-is to one input tensor, as the matrix is not square/uniformed, and i can only describe square shapes when calling `tflearn.input_data`, so for example:

```
input_data = n.array([
    [0.4, -0.3, 0.43, 0.23],
    [0.4, -0.3, 0.43, 0.23],
])
input_data = n.reshape(input_data, [-1, 4, 1])
input_layer = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 4, 1], name='input')
```

If i got it right, what happens here is: we convert each element of each input set to a tuple of 1 element:

```
>>> input_data = n.reshape(input_data, [-1, 4, 1])
>>> input_data
array([[[ 0.4 ],
        [-0.3 ],
        [ 0.43],
        [ 0.23]],

       [[ 0.4 ],
        [-0.3 ],
        [ 0.43],
        [ 0.23]]])
```

And when we call `tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 4, 1], name='input')` we are saying: `None` because we dont specify the batch size, so the length of the first vector will be adjusted as needed, `4` and `1` as each input set now consists of 4 arrays which each have 1 element. (..? Or is it "and each of the 4 arrays contains 1 array"?)

So question is: 
 - is it somehow magically possible to feed data like that / describe a non-square shape (so for the first data it would be something like "Input data is an array of n-length where each entry is an array with 2 1d arrays which have length of 4 and 2."
 - if that is not possible, what is the best way to deal with this kind of input data? We could pad the input data of the smaller vectors with `0`, but i'm not sure if that is a good idea? As an alternative, we could create two separate input tensors and use a network that supports multiple input tensors. On a first glance, that sounds cleaner to me, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Option three: simply merging the two vectors to one. Seems to work fine so far.